# После обновления index.html сайт перестал работать на Github Pages

Tags: github, github-pages

До этого он нормально работал.
Подскажите, что нужно сделать, чтобы отображался сайт?
Я уже побывал заново создавать, но не получилось. Файлы загружал через браузер.

Comment: Локально открывается сайт? Что пишет в консоли инспектора в браузере?

Comment: Локально отрывается